# The Hessian quadratic form of a real function can't be complex

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C^n$ open, $z_0\in\Omega$, $r:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ twice real differentiable.

We know $\Bbb C^n\simeq\Bbb R^{2n}$ is an isomorphism of vect.sp. So we think $\Bbb C^{n}$ as an $\Bbb R$-space, so it has dimension $2n$. A base for it is given by $z_1,\dots,z_n,\bar z_1,\dots,\bar z_n$. So $\Bbb C^n\simeq\Bbb C^n\times\overline{\Bbb C}^n$.

The Hessian matrix of $r$ in $z_0$ is the $2n\times2n$ matrix 
$$
\operatorname{hess}r_{z_0}=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_{z_i}\partial_{z_j}r(z_0) & \partial_{z_i}\partial_{\bar z_j}r(z_0) \\
\partial_{\bar z_i}\partial_{z_j}r(z_0) & \partial_{\bar z_i}\partial_{\bar z_j}r(z_0)
\end{array}
\right]_{i,j=1,\dots,n}=:
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{array}
\right]
\;\;\;.
$$
Clearly $A,B,C,D\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ (they are real since $r$ is such), they are all symmetric and $A=D, B=C$.

Now we define the Levi form of $r$ as the bilinear hermitian form whose matrix is given by block $B$ (or $C$, they are equal), i.e. the $n\times n$ matrix
$$
L_r(z_0)=B=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\partial_{z_i}\partial_{\bar z_j}r(z_0)
\end{array}
\right]_{i,j=1,\dots,n}\;\;\;.
$$
i.e. the form is given by $(v,u)\mapsto\;^TvB\bar u$, where $(v,u)\in\Bbb C^n\times\Bbb C^n$.

My book is very very cryptic, it doesn't say where this form comes out; it clearly comes out from the bilinear form induced by the hessian, which is defined on $\Bbb C^n\times\Bbb C^n$:
\begin{align*}
(v,u)\mapsto[^Tv,^T\bar v]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
u \\
\bar u
\end{array}
\right]
&=\;^TvAu+\;^TvB\bar u+\;^T\bar vCu+\;^T\bar vD\bar u
\end{align*}
so the Levi form is "a piece" of the hessian.

**ATTENTION**: I've deduced this last formula by myself!! Is that correct?

Now it should be immediate to see that
$$
\;^TvAu+\;^T\bar vD\bar u=\;^TvAu+\;\overline{^TvAu}=2\Re(^TvAu)
$$
and similarly
$$
\;^TvB\bar u+\;^T\bar vCu=\;^TvB\bar u+\;^T\bar vBu=\;^TvB\bar u+\overline{\;^TvB\bar u}=2\Re(\;^TvB\bar u)\;.
$$
In this way, the hessian form should be 
$$
[^Tv,^T\bar v]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
u \\
\bar u
\end{array}
\right]=
2\Re(^TvAu+\;^TvB\bar u)
$$

My book, writes all this as follows (he thinks the hessian as the quadratic term in Taylor series of $r$ so he divides by $2$, so what follows should be what I wrote but divided by $2$):
$$
\operatorname{hess}r_{z_0}=\frac12\sum_{i,j=1}^n\partial_{z_i}\partial_{z_j}r(z_0)\,dz_i\otimes dz_j+\\
+\frac12\sum_{i,j=1}^n\partial_{\bar z_i}\partial_{\bar z_j}r(z_0)\,d\bar z_i\otimes d\bar z_j+
\sum_{i,j=1}^n\partial_{z_i}\partial_{\bar z_j}r(z_0)\,dz_i\otimes d\bar z_j
$$
but to me is senseless because of the third term: if the book was right it should be
$$
\;^TvB\bar u=\;^T\bar vCu
$$
but this is not true! Where is the error?!

Moreover the hessian form is a piece of the Taylor expansion of $r$, which is a real function; writing as the book does, $r$ could be even complex!

Am I right? Many thanks!

Comment: Generally, $A,B,C,D$ are not real matrices. $A$ and $D$ are symmetric, and $D = \overline{A}$, $B$ and $C$ are hermitian with $C = \overline{B} = B^T$.

Comment: Many thanks Daniel! But how can those matrices are not real? Their entries are derivatives of $r$ which is a real valued function. And -most important- how can I prove or disprove the relation 
$$
^TvB\bar u=\;^T\bar vCu\;\;?
$$
Many thanks Daniel

Comment: Recall that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}\bigl(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\bigr)$. The Wirtinger derivatives are not real operators, you can get non-real output from real inputs.

Comment: Ok ok maybe the last relation I wrote could follow from these observation. Many thanks

Comment: No no it doesn't work:
$$
^T\bar vCu=\;^T\bar v\bar Bu=\overline{^TvB\bar u}\neq\;^TvB\bar u
$$
how can I go out from this?

Comment: @DanielFischer: however do you agree with the fact that $r$ is a real valued function implies that the hessian bilinear form should be real?

Comment: Yes, the Hesse form is real (note: it is probably better to be explicit and write $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear to avoid any inkling of $\mathbb{C}$-bilinearity, since we also deal with complex numbers). We have ${}^T\overline{v}D\overline{u} = \overline{{}^Tv A u}$ since $D = \overline{A}$, and ${}^T\overline{v} C u = \overline{{}^TvB\overline{u}}$ since $C = \overline{B}$, so altogether we have something real.

Comment: Thus you agree with me, when I say the book is wrong in writing that last sum in the hessian form!

Comment: But: The Levi form is a sesquilinear form on $\mathbb{C}^n$, it is _not_ real-valued [except in the trivial case that it's $\equiv 0$]. However, it's a hermitian form, so ${}^T\overline{u} B u$ is real.

Comment: Probably, the $\otimes$ denotes the symmetric tensor product of the forms, so $(dz_i \otimes d\overline{z}_j)(u,v) = u_i\overline{v}_j + \overline{u}_jv_i$, then I think it matches.